# why isn't the Django dev server reloading?

Tags: django

I've used django dev servers for years.  I start them with

```
python manage.py runserver
```

and when I change any of the python code, they restart nicely.

Now I've inherited someone else's project for maintenance, and for whatever reason, I change the Python code and the server does not restart.  I can't seem to find any kind of configuration option that would cause this.

I don't have the `--noreload` flag set, here's my proof:

```
$ ps -ef | grep runserver
chris     290898  250765  1 11:55 pts/6    00:00:00 python manage.py runserver
chris     290914  290898  5 11:55 pts/6    00:00:01 /home/chris/.virtualenvs/my-webapp-4cLYw-9X/bin/python manage.py runserver
```

Has anyone run into this before?

- Python 3.9.5
- Django 3.2.6
- using pipenv to manage my virtual environment

**UPDATE**

More info...equally as odd

the project is set up like this

```
src/manage.py
src/myproject (contains settings.py, urls.py, etc)
src/apps/app_one (contains models.py, tests.py, etc)
src/apps/app_two (contains models.py, tests.py, etc)
```

If I edit any file under src/myproject, then the server restarts as expected.  But if I edit files under app_one or app_two, then the server does not restart.

**UPDATE #2**

Resurrecting this before it drives me crazy (it may be too late).

I added `django.utils.autoreload': {'level': 'DEBUG'},` to `settings.LOGGING`, and now I can see that Django is watching my files, because I can see this in the logs:

> [15/Feb/2022 10:58:14] django.utils.autoreload - DEBUG [tick:392] File
> /home/chris/OBFUSCATED/src/apps/account/models.py previous
> mtime: 1644940666.8954673, current mtime: 1644940693.9396086

> [15/Feb/2022 10:58:14] django.utils.autoreload - DEBUG
> [notify_file_changed:366]
> /home/chris/OBFUSCATED/src/apps/account/models.py notified
> as changed. Signal results: [(<function template_changed at
> 0x7efd4b77b550>, True), (<function translation_file_changed at
> 0x7efd48257f70>, None)].

And yet, the dev server does not restart.  Hoping this makes more sense to someone than it does to me.

Comment: What happens when you visit a url, is anything printed out to the console?

Comment: Could you check if your predecessor perhaps made a custom `runserver` command? You'd be looking for a `management/commands` folder with a file containing a `Command` class, which is a subclass of `django.core.management.commands.runserver.Command`.

Comment: @MichalKrejčí -- I'm not seeing anything like that.  In fact, I added the django-sslserver package and I get he same behavior when running "python manage.py runsslserver"  Great thought, tho!

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE**

This is fixed in [Django 3.2.13](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/releases/3.2.13/) and [Django 4.0.4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/releases/4.0.4/)

**Original answer**

I have a similar issue, and it appears to be a bug. I tracked it down to Django 3.2.4 (3.2.3 works as expected).

See the [Release notes for Django 3.2.4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/releases/3.2.4/). [This is the bugfix](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/32744) that breaks it for me.

It's still broken as of 4.0.3.

**UPDATE**

In my case this is due to having `['']` in DIRS, use filter if you are getting the value from the enviroment:

```py
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": filter(None, os.getenv("TEMPLATES_DIRS", "").split(",")),
...
```

I've opened a [bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/33628) and a [PR](https://github.com/django/django/pull/15572)

Comment: Did you find a workaround? Seems to be affecting us as well.

Comment: @apod yes, look at the updated answer

Comment: i am getting this in 3.2.13

Answer (score 4):

Have had the same issue. I finally identified the issue. In my `settings.TEMPLATES`, the `DIRS` was `[BASE_DIR]`, while it should be `[BASE_DIR / 'templates']`.
Once I fixed this, autoreload worked again.

Comment: hmm, I already have "templates" in TEMPLATES['DIRS']....but my issue is that changes to **python** files don't trigger a restart.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you solved this or not, but I ran into a similar problem. I did some digging and this django ticket led me in the right direction: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/33473

tldr is that the server won't reload if it thinks the changed file is in a templates directory, or in a nested sub directory of a templates directory. This is by design. And by the results of your debug logs, that seems to be the case.

> results: [(<function template_changed at 0x7efd4b77b550>, True), (<function translation_file_changed at 0x7efd48257f70>, None)]

This file provides some insight into what is happening.
Specifically `template_changed()` and `get_template_directories()`functions: https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.2.x/django/template/autoreload.py

For me, the issue was that I had a line in my local django settings file that was adding the project root directory in to the `TEMPLATES['DIRS']` setting, causing the autoreload func to think that every file was in a template directory, and therefore not performing a reload.

So, boot up a django shell and check your `TEMPLATES['DIRS']` list and make sure there isn't an entry in there that could contain files that you would want to trigger a reload.

Something else to do would be to check any template loaders you have configured and ensure they aren't doing something similar. That is, returning a dir from their `get_dirs()` call that would contain files you want watched by the autoreloader. Relevant source code: https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.2.x/django/template/autoreload.py#L28

Answer (score 0):

Auto-reloading is a feature of Django runserver and is only used in development mode.

read this in [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/):

> If you’re using Linux or MacOS and install both pywatchman and the Watchman service, kernel signals will be used to autoreload the server (rather than polling file modification timestamps each second). This offers better performance on large projects, reduced response time after code changes, more robust change detection, and a reduction in power usage. Django supports pywatchman 1.2.0 and higher.

But in production mode servers run by wsgi.py file and managed by python servers like gunicorn, uwsgi, ...

This feature is not preferred in production mode because you may need to change multiple files and you save them one by one and auto-reload may cause error pages in production.

Comment: How does this answer OP's question?

Comment: the question is edited after this answer

Comment: Both the original version and the two edits clearly state that django is run in development mode, and production is never mentioned. The edits didn't significantly change the question.

Comment: you're right great officer!