# Django server not reloading on file changes

Tags: python, django, django-settings

I just cloned a Django project from my Github for maintenance on another machine, installed all the dependencies then ran the server. Everything seems to be working fine except the fact that the server does not reload when I make file changes (on all python files). Changes in static files are not reflected too. Things to note:

- Django 4.0.3
- Python 3.9.0
- Environment manager is Pipenv.

**Settings.py**

```py
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
```

I don't have a custom `runserver` command
I have the suggestions on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68974685/why-isnt-the-django-dev-server-reloading) but they didn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71618373/14457833) it's a bug which is in ***Django 4.0.3*** so try to downgrade your ***Django*** version to ***3.2***. I'll suggest to read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68977712/14457833)

Comment: Just downgraded to that version but still isn't working. Though I just saw an error while starting the terminal `...cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this 
system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.` Do you think this could be affecting the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reload all static files in the browser you need to press `ctrl + f5` (refreshes cache)

Also, make sure to run the `python manage.py collectstatic` command to save all static files in a single directory or even use compressed storage.

For all python files, make sure that `autosave` is enabled on Visual Studio Code (I have faced this issue too)

Comment: Thanks this worked. Refreshed the `cache` and enabled `autosave`