# Django dev server does not automatically reload after saving files

Tags: django

I tested Django 3 a few months ago, and it all worked well. The browser refreshed itself after I made a change to files (.html and .py).

Now I have an issue with a newly created Django project, the browser doesn't automatically reload after I saved a change that I made on my local machine.

```
OS: Windows 11
Editor: PyCharm / VS Code
Django 4.0.4
Python 3.10.4
```

Directory structure

```
project/
├── project/
│   ├── ...
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── ...
├── first_app/
│   ├── ...
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── views.y
│   └── ...
├── templates/
│   └── first_app/
│       └── index_view.html
└── manage.py
```

Default settings.py file with

```
....
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   ...
   'first_app',
   ...
]

'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates']
....
```

project/urls.py

```
....
urlpatterns = [
   path('', include('first_app.urls')
]
....
```

first_app/views.py

```
....
class IndexView(generic.TemplateView):
   template_name = 'first_app/index_view.html'
...
```

first_app/urls.py

```
....
urlpatterns = [
   path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index')
]
....
```

templates/first_app/index_view.html

```
....
<p>
   Test paragraph 1
</p>
....
```

I run the server locally with `py manage.py runserver`

When I change '*paragraph*' to '*example*' in index_view.html and save it, it is supposed to automatically refresh the browser and display **Test example 1**. But the browser doesn't reload.

I have created new Django projects several times and the results are still the same.
Am I missing something?

I have tried the solutions on the following questions, but none of the solutions work for me.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68974685/why-isnt-the-django-dev-server-reloading/71618373\](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68974685/why-isnt-the-django-dev-server-reloading/71618373%5C)
[Django server not reloading on file changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72335586/django-server-not-reloading-on-file-changes)

Update:
`py manage.py runserver` output

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
May 25, 2022 - 21:40:08
Django version 4.0.4, using settings 'project.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

Comment: Hi there, Can you update your question with "what you get when you run `runserver` command"

Comment: Are you expecting the _browser_ to reload by itself, or the Django test server to reload?  The latter is expected (so you don’t need to restart the test server on changes), but the browser doesn’t reload itself on changes.  You have to hit refresh.

Comment: @RajaSimon Hi, added the output when `runserver`

Comment: @taherh I guess it is browser. I recorded a test of my previous project to show the 
[desired behavior](https://i.ibb.co/sVDYvF4/demo.gif)

Comment: Try **control S** to save everything before refreshing your browser maybe your **CodeEditor** doesn't save it **automatically**

Comment: @HTT I see — that behavior (auto *browser* refresh) is actually a feature of your IDE (PyCharm), not Django.  Perhaps your PyCharm config changed.  See this link: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/editing-html-files.html#ws_configure_auto_reload

Comment: @DeeAdamu I already did that. The browser stays still, which means I need to manually refresh the browser every time I made changes.

Comment: @taherh I have tested it with VS Code and the behavior of my old project is the same as the gif I shared, which is reloading the browser when I made changes.

Comment: @HTT Not sure about your exact setup, but it’s definitely related to your IDE — Django itself has no way of refreshing your browser directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Note: I'm capturing the summary of the discussion in the comments -- you found the actual problem in the end)

By default, Django is only able to reload the test server on code or template changes, it is not able to refresh the browser automatically.

If your browser was refreshing the page by itself for your previous projects, either it was triggered by a signal from your IDE, or by some javascript in your pages that was forcing a refresh.

It turns out you had the third-party package [django-browser-reload](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-browser-reload) installed in your previous projects, which injects a small script into your pages that refresh the page whenever the Django test server reloads.  Adding that package to your new project will resolve the issue.